# Dynamic indoor mapping in Native android

Tags: geoserver, android, indoor

I'm about to work on a project, in which we have to create an indoor map to locate articles inside our store. I have created different layers in QGIS (store, showrooms, articles) shapefiles and published them in geoserver. What I need is an opensource way to get the services from geoserver to show data on an android native application.

The problem is that the store can be changed each 15 days, so I have the DWG file if you could give me any alternative solutions so I don't have to digitize the store again.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use a database. The geometries are created once, and when your store content is changed you update a table linked to the geometry.

Table one: shelveID, geometry

Table 2: shelveID, productID

In geoserver you can publish a view joining these 2 tables (or more, with product details), which automatically reflect updates made to them

Comment: Thank you, this is what i thought about hopping not to face problems using android maps with Geoserver.